# Sqoop Import failed : Please specify one with --split-by or perform a sequential import with '-m 1' Error even after setting mapper = 1

Tags: sqoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I am importing a table from SQL Server to Hive.

```
sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:sqlserver://<server-name>:<port-no>;database=<database-name>" \
--username <user-name> \
-P \
--table <table-name> \
-- --schema <schema-name> \
--hive-import \
--hive-database <hive-database-name> \
--hive-table <hive-table-name> \
--target-dir /tmp \
-m 1
```

The table does not have primary key so I have added -m 1 (to run one mapper), but I am still getiing error to set '-m 1'.

ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: No primary key could be found for table. Please specify one with --split-by or perform a sequential import with '-m 1'.

I am working on a 3 node cluster and version details are:

Distribution : Hortonrowks HDP3.0

Sqoop : 1.4

Hive : 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use only one dash with `m` param: `-m 1` (not `--m 1`) and move `-- --schema <schema-name>` to the end of command since the Sqoop CLI has the following structure:

```
sqoop TOOL PROPERTY_ARGS SQOOP_ARGS [-- EXTRA_ARGS]
```

Comment: Sorry, It was only -m 1 (NOT --m 1). This was a typo only.

Comment: Maybe your problem links with args order: the CLI has the following structure: sqoop TOOL PROPERTY_ARGS SQOOP_ARGS [-- EXTRA_ARGS]. Try to move `-- --schema <schema-name>` to the end of command or avoid using it (`--table <schema-name>.<table-name>`).

Comment: If I move -- --schema argument to  end of argument like, sqoop issues the query but throws error 

`ERROR hook.AtlasHook: Failed to send notification - attempt #1; error=Missing required configuration "bootstrap.servers" which has no default value.`
`ERROR hook.AtlasHook: Failed to send notification - attempt #2; error=Missing required configuration "bootstrap.servers" which has no default value.`
`org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "bootstrap.servers" which has no default value.`

Comment: If I combine schema and table name like schema.tablename, it throws error that table does not exists.

Comment: It is another issue. I think you can temporary disable Sqoop hook to check that import is ok (https://atlas.apache.org/Hook-Sqoop.html). Or solve this issue by adding required conf param `bootstrap.servers` (https://atlas.apache.org/Configuration.html). If you can't solve by yourself, you could post new question to SO. Anyway solution for your original problem is to move `-- --schema <schema-name>` to the end of command. I've updated my answer: if it is aprecable for you, please accept and vote up.